# Can two Celery applications share the same queue?

Tags: python, celery

I have two celery applications, each has a different task.

App 1 has `task_one`
App 2 has `task_two`

Can both apps share the same Celery queue?

How does Celery route `task_one` to App 1 instead of App 2?

I haven't tried running this yet.